# How could I use transmission data from another environment texture?

Tags: shaders, light, lighting, hdri, world

In this setup **I made the ship lighting come from a Nishita Sky Texture and the clouds + ocean reflection come from an HDRI** by using the **Light Path** node.

[image]

But what's wrong is the **transmission/reflection** in the ocean. It **should come from the HDRI** instead of from the Nishita Sky Texture.

Here's how it looks with the **setup I showed above** (notice all the sand-looking transmissions/reflections coming from the**Nishita Sky Texture**):

[image]

Here's how it looks when I preview the **HDRI only** (it should be like this but with the ship being lit by the Nishita Sky Texture instead, so that I can make the lighting more dynamic without affecting the ocean):

[image]

**So, how could I make the transmission color come from the HDRI instead of from the Nishita Sky Texture?**
I've already tried the obvious stuff, such as plugging the “Is Transmission Ray” output of the Light Path node into another Math (Add) node, but it didn't work. I also tried tweaking the ocean shader: decreasing the Roughness to 0 removes the ugly reflections, but it makes the water look super nasty and over-processed. Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: Hey :). Cheating physics in a physically based engine sometimes introduces more problems than it solves...

Comment: Hmm you're probably right, but here's how the sails looked before... really, really flat and boring: https://imgur.com/a/MsEhlOQ

Comment: Try LightPaths node for it.

Answer (score 4):

Sorry if I misunderstand your desired setup, but try something like this and let me know if it works for you - It "works" the way I think it should, but I'm not sure that matches what you have in mind. The sky (image) is Nishita. The Cube is default white, the sphere is pure reflective (metallic 1, roughness 0) - the sphere reflects the Nishita sky, except for a bit at the bottom which is picking up a bit of the HDRI texture from the transmission in the "water". And as you can see, the water is picking up the transmission from the HDRI (which has several "reddish" sections).

If this is no good, I'll delete the answer:

[image: Shaderz]